# Laravel - xampp could not find driver (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I'm using **Laravel 8** and **Xampp (v3.2.4) - ** and configured phpunit.xml to run the tests on sqlite_testing (memory).

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite_testing"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>

database.php
'sqlite_testing' => [
  'driver' => 'sqlite',
  'database' => ':memory:'
],
```

when i run  ./vendor/bin/phpunit --color --testdox i'm getting this error:

- Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)

In order to solve this, i've tried:

- on php.ini uncomment **extension=pdo_sqlite**, **extension=sqlite3** and fill the **sqlite3.extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"**
- copied c:\xampp\php\ext\libsqlite3.dll to C:\xampp\apache\bin
- php artisan config:clear (after updating database.php)
- composer update
- composer require doctrine/dbal
- checked  php -m for PDO

Nothing worked. Still getting the error message:

```
   ├ Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)
```

Comment: I think it's better to write in the config/app.php instead of ENV file, test it.
and after that write the error that you get after enabling  extension=pdo_sqlite, extension=sqlite3 ?

Comment: @SamRaskul thanks for the answer, the problem was that besides xampp i had another php version installed on my machine. So when enabled sqlite on that php.ini file it worked without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow that steps.

```
1 step: sudo apt install sqlite3
2 step: sudo apt-get install php7.4-sqlite3 -y
3 step: php -m | grep sqlite
4 step: .env

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE={absolute_path}/database.sqlite
#DB_FOREIGN_KEYS=true
#DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
#DB_PORT=3306
#DB_DATABASE=homestead
#DB_USERNAME=homestead
#DB_PASSWORD=secret
```